# Understanding setup.py arguments and how to launch when installed

Tags: command-line, software-installation, python

quite the vague-ish title, sorry.

I recently picked up linux after understanding some basics and a new(old pre-1st gen, Core i7, 2010) laptop.
I'm fairly adequate in Windows, but I've never built and installed something using the python cmd line.

1)
I followed the readme, I installed Python, setuptools, pillow, pygtk like the readme advised, using `aptitude search namehere` then `sudo apt install namehere` and then finally `sudo python2 setup.py install`
tried to get it to install in a dir using `--prefix=/home/namehere/Desktop/Programs` but it kept giving me
`You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.`
gave up and just followed the default `setup.py install` so if anyone could explain where I went wrong, I would like to know the answer for future installs.

2)
Now that the program has installed, readme says it will be located in `usr/bin` , (I am trying to install MComix, CDisplayEX alternative, comic reader), found mcomix python script file located in `usr/local/bin` I was expecting a shortcut or an icon in my Applications that I could search for and run, but now Im stumped on the next step.

I just dont have that Linux vernacular to google-fu up the answer like I do with Windows issues. so all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all applications create a desktop launcher.

Setup routines usually install the application (command to start the application) into a directory that is in the user's search path by default.  The most common areas are the one you mentioned, `/usr/bin` as well as, `/usr/local/bin`.

Programs installed in those paths are command line launchers to tart the program.  It can usually be identified by the actual name itself.

You mentioned that you are not fluent with building and installing Linux programs.  So with that as a consideration, you'd best not try to customize the installation, but install it with its defaults.

In this case, looking at the description of your question the install package does have some safeguard flags and is warning you not to change the configuration files to put the launch command in an area not in your search path.

Install the application without changes by its defaults.  Look at the Readme file, which will include install procedures as well as (normally) steps on how to start the application.

Look in the two most command directories for commands `/usr/bin` and /usr/local/bin`.  You can view the most recent additions to those areas with this command (the most recent will be on top).  Look for commands closer to the time of the installation.

```
$ ls -lt /usr/bin | less
$ ls -lt /usr/local/bin | less
```

Less is a pager that will allow you to use the arrow keys to scroll up and down to view the contents of those two directories.  The `ls -lt` will give a detailed list including the time of the creation sorted by time with the most recent on top.

If you install the program and don't get any errors, you'll find the commands there.

Search those areas the same way you have already familiarized yourself with checking the `/usr/share/applications` space for program launchers.

The commands you see in that listing can be executed just by typing the command in the terminal.

**Creating a desktop launcher**

You can create your own desktop launcher for the program by running this command:

```
$ gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

After you have created the launcher, place the new launcher in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`.  It will then appear in your Ubuntu search button.

Comment: Creating that desktop launcher, I'm confused which part of the gnome command should I edit?  from the looks of it it looks like all it does is launch the `Desktop`

Comment: It will launch the command you type or browse to in the  for the `Command` field.  What did you place in the `Command` field?